# Reload watchOS complications after timeline ends

Tags: watchkit, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I do not understand how I can reliable reload the complication timeline on watchOS **after the current timeline ends**.

In *getTimelineEndDate:forComplication:withHandler* (*CLKComplicationDataSource*) I'm returning the end of the current day.

My expectation was, that watchOS will automatically perform a timeline reload after this date, otherwise what sense has this method?

I tried to schedule a background application refresh when the timeline ends (midnight) and reload all active complications in there, but it seems that watchOS does not perform these tasks if the Watch is on a charger. Moreover it does not immediately schedule it after the Watch is unlocked (example, in the morning).

What am I missing? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you resolved this?